# how to get value of an element using getElementById and getElementsByTagName together

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pretty-print

I am trying to `prettyprint` the value of `<pre>` element for which I will be getting either xml or JSON as string, so I am trying to get the value first and then test if it is xml or json and call respective prettyprint methods here is my code  ...

```
function showData(attName) {
    var attData = document.getElementById(attName).getElementsByTagName('pre')[0];
    alert(attData);
    // once I get the value would like to test whether it is xml or json
    //if (attData contains xml test condition )
          prettyPrint.xml(attData);
    else prettyPrint.json(attData);

    document.getElementById('Details').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById(attName).style.display='block';
}
```

So the `showData` will be called whenever I click on View link in the below code ..

```
<div id="Details" class="body">
    <a href="javascript:showData('${attachmentName}')">View</a>
</div>
<div id="${attachmentName}" style="display:none; margin-left:60px; margin-top:5px;position:absolute;background-color:#F8F8F8;padding:10px" >
    <h1>${attachmentName}:${attachmentId}</h1>

    <a href="javascript:hideData('${attachmentName}')"><h5 style="color: #FF0066;"> [X Close] </h5></a> <br/>

    <pre class="prettyprint">${attachmentData}</pre>
</div>
```

In alert I am getting `[object HTMLPreElement]` but not sure how to make it to string, so I have also tried ...

```
var objectHTMLCollection = document.getElementById(attName).getElementsByTagName('pre')[0],
    string = [].map.call( objectHTMLCollection, function(node){
        return node.textContent || node.innerText || "";
    }).join("");
alert (objectHTMLCollection);
```

But still getting as `HTMLPreElement`...

I have tried the JQuery `jQuery('#'+attName).find('.prettyprint').data();` but got the result as `[object Object]` . 
I don't have much exposure in the JavaScript,may be I am not doing it in right way. It would be great if anyone can help on this.

Comment: With jquery, you can do this way: _var my_text = $("#id_pre").html();_

Comment: ID is specific to one single element on the page. Why would you try to add getElementByTagName?

Comment: @Shivam He's getting the first "pre" tag inside a div with the specified ID.

Comment: Thanks to all I have tried `document.getElementById(attName).getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;`  and `var my_text = $("#id_pre").html();` worked well

Answer (score 2):

Add .innerHTML - should work, get rid of the complicated mapping functions that are meant to work with multiple `<pre>` tags at once.

```
      var attData = document.getElementById(attName).getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;
      alert(attData);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery:

```
var text = $("#" + attName + " pre:first").text();
```

That gets you the text content of the element.

Comment: sorry, I get empty string for this. Is it because I have empty string very first in the value?

Comment: That code gets you the contents of the first `<pre>` element found under the container with the "id" you're using. What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your last js snippet is close, but you're calling map on a non-array object, and passing the wrong var to alert(). To find all 'pre' elements:

```
var objectHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
var str = [].map.call( objectHTMLCollection, function(node){
    return node.textContent || node.innerText || "";
  }).join("");
alert (str);
```

If you are actually only looking for one 'pre' element:

```
var htmlObject = document.getElementById(attName);
var str = htmlObject.textContent || htmlObject.innerText || "";
alert (str);
```

Remember, an element's id is unique, so there's no point in querying by id, and tag name.